# Codeigniter | 15% of HTML emails are blank

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Currently have a form, where the user uploads 4 attachments. These attachments are uploaded to the server and then attached to an email then emailed.

I have everything setup and during most tests the email with attachments sends properly. However some times the email are sent as blank. ie.) One user allows gets a blank email, and whenever I test, it's successful.

Not sure why.. I'm using CodeIgniter, and not seeing why some of go blank and are sent properly.

I'm trying to use : echo $this->email->print_debugger();

However, it's always successful on my side.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/redrory/2fe2eac68ae3e27c2a42

**Gist of blank email here:** https://gist.github.com/redrory/2c46eddc6f7fad86b38c

I believe, it be because. The domain is hosting is on domain.com but the email is (from) is another. See **X-AntiAbuse** in logs

```
function test_upload()
{
  $this->load->view('am_header');
  $this->load->library('email');
  $this->load->helper('date');
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Jamaica');
  $dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $this->load->library('upload');
  $this->email->subject('My Form');
  $this->email->from('form@mydomain.com', 'Life Form');
  $this->email->set_mailtype("html");

    // personal
  $data['date'] = $dateTime;

  $data['terms'] = $this->input->post('terms');
  $data['first_name'] = $this->input->post('first_name');
  $data['middle_name'] = $this->input->post('middle_name');
  $data['last_name'] = $this->input->post('last_name');
  $nummy =  random_string('alnum', 16);

  $data['nummy'] = $nummy;
  $files = $_FILES;
  $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
  $vary = array('PHOTO','RESUME','JOB','PHOTO2');
  for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
  {
      $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];

        $new_name = $vary[$i] .$nummy .$_FILES["userfile"]['name'];
        $this->upload->initialize($this->test_set_upload_options($new_name));

      if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        redirect('main/error_contact');
      }
      else{
          $this->email->attach("testuploads/" . $new_name);
      }
  }

  $this->email->to('redme@myemail.com');
  $this->main_model->add_records_test($data);
  $message = $this->load->view('contact_template',$data,TRUE); // this will return you html data as message
  $this->email->message($message);

    if ($data2['smile']=='') {
      if ($this->email->send() ) {
        redirect('main/thanks_contact');
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
      }else{
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        redirect('main/error_contact');
    }
}

private function test_set_upload_options($new_name)
{
    //upload an image options
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './testuploads/';
    // $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|jpeg|zip|doc|docx';
    $config['max_size']      = '0';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
    $config['file_name'] = $new_name;

    return $config;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? Might be an issue with php or the page that is causing some variable to be blank. On debian linux systems (ubuntu) the error logs reside at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Other systems will be similar.

Comment: Maybe there are unusual characters or tags inside message. Tell user to send only attachments without message. Escape email body. Maybe it's email client...

Comment: Hey @JonathanKuhn - The application is  currently in a folder on the main domain, there is an application error, however that only contains application specific errors, and nothing is showing. Checking on the root

Comment: Hey @cssBlaster21895 Currently when they upload attachments only and enter one field, it's still blank. I'm thinking, if the attachment is taking too long to upload before the email sends, however it's actually uploads to the server successfully.

Comment: The php page isn't called until the file has been uploaded. The file is sent as part of the request. Until the request is done sending, the response is not even started. So if the file is taking too long, it wouldn't even get to the php script to send the email. It is possible that the file is too large and so the email is failing to go through. Or like cssBlaster is saying. Is the email sent as an html email? And the php error log should still be written to if there are php errors. I was more curious about php errors over an application error.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Yes, it's been sent as html. I don't quite think it's the attachment be too longs, as the sizes of the attachments that are uploaded is under 100 kb. The error_log within the application folder, isn't logging any errors from today. Checking on the root, if i can find another php error log

Comment: 100k is not really large so I doubt that is the problem. It might be like cssBlaster is saying and an html tag is not being closed and so you don't see any of the content. Could you view the html source of the email and confirm that there is actually no content and not just malformed html.

Comment: Hey @JonathanKuhn- I added the gist of the blank email header with my assumptions above.

Comment: Hey @cssBlaster21895 I added the gist of the blank email header

Answer (score 0):

You're not always printing the `print_debugger()` call.

It can be simplified to...

```
// $data2 is never defined, so remove that if which is always TRUE
// if ($data2['smile']=='') {

$status = $this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();

if ($status) {
    redirect('main/thanks_contact');
} else {
    redirect('main/error_contact');
}
```